# How can I list all videos that are only visible to me on Vimeo?

Tags: vimeo

I'd like to list all videos that are only visible to me on Vimeo: how can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you trying to build this via the API?

Comment: No, just as a simple user using the user interface. But if it's not possible, I'm curious about which API method can achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

When building an off site list of Vimeo videos, you will need to use the API.

Vimeo's new API has a lot of the features you need, and you can get started here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

The above link will walk you through app creation, and then the endpoint varies based on the videos you want to see. It's pretty intuitive though, so start here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints

If you want to see your videos, request `/me/videos`. If you want to see all videos in the staff picks channel, request `/channels/staffpicks/videos`.

Make sure to read the [Authentication](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication) documentation, I expect you are building a Single User application and can hard code your authentication token into your app.